# What is the recommended route from Salt Lake to PHX in winter weather?

Tags: usa, driving, winter, mountains, snow

There is snow in the forecast and I was scheduled to drive from SLC to PHX on  Saturday, but now I may have to leave today. What is the recommended route in these conditions?

Comment: PHX, like Phoenix airport ?

Answer (score 1):

With good winter tires, any of the normal routes should be fine.  More major highways tend to get more frequent snowplow visits.  I-15 to US-89 to I-17 seems to be the most expedient route.

With all-season tires, you will have to check on the expected snowfalls and the elevation of the passes through which you may drive.  Some of the higher elevations may require you to carry snow chains, and if so, you should know how to use them.